# MongoD Start Hangs Indefinitely at Connections:0

Tags: mongodb, centos

```
mongod --smallfiles
2014-06-05T13:19:15.085-0400 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=14584 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=sfpop-predict06
2014-06-05T13:19:15.085-0400 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.1
2014-06-05T13:19:15.085-0400 [initandlisten] git version: 4b95b086d2374bdcfcdf2249272fb552c9c726e8
2014-06-05T13:19:15.085-0400 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build14.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-06-05T13:19:15.085-0400 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-06-05T13:19:15.085-0400 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { smallFiles: true } }
2014-06-05T13:19:15.091-0400 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-06-05T13:19:15.091-0400 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-06-05T13:19:15.113-0400 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-06-05T13:20:15.137-0400 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:35 virt:327
2014-06-05T13:20:15.137-0400 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):64
2014-06-05T13:20:15.138-0400 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

It hangs for a minute on the "waiting for connections on port 27017" line, and indefinitely on the "connections:0" line. I can run Mongo just fine, but I need to run MongoD so I can connect to the databases with PHP. How can I fix this?

CentOS 5.7

Comment: This is the normal startup waiting state for mongod. Have you tried connecting the mongo shell? If you run mongo it should connect to this mongod instance and you should see a connection created.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same doubt as you, What James said is right, just start another terminal, and run mongo, it will be connected automatically